# cannot read OTP from message

Tags: android, one-time-password

i m trying to read OTP from message, but i cant auto read it.please tell me what i did wrong, here is my code.i m using marshmallow. thank you.

here is my SmsReceiver class:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static SmsListener mListener;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle data  = intent.getExtras();

    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) data.get("pdus");

    for(int i=0;i<pdus.length;i++){
        SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

        String sender = smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
        //You must check here if the sender is your provider and not another one with same text.

        String messageBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();

        //Pass on the text to our listener.
       mListener.messageReceived(messageBody);
    }

}

public static void bindListener(SmsListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}}
```

here is interface

```
  public interface SmsListener {
    public void messageReceived(String messageText);
   }
```

and this is my activity

```
 public class MyOTP extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText txtotp;
Button btnSubmitOtp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_otp);

    txtotp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtOtp);
    btnSubmitOtp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

    btnSubmitOtp.setOnClickListener(this);

    SmsReceiver.bindListener(new SmsListener() {
        @Override
        public void messageReceived(String messageText) {
            Log.d("Text",messageText);
            Toast.makeText(MyOTP.this,"Message: "+messageText,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: check you permissions in manifest.:)Paste your manifest

Comment: check if you have registered the receiver in manifest file

Comment: ya i have added permission in my manifest also registered the receiver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my working Broadcast receiver class which will read digits from message body & broadcast with OTP code to related class

You need to add these permissions in menifest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Here is my receiver class

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           //---get the SMS message passed in---
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String msg_from;
            if (bundle != null) {
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                try {
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 22) {
                            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                        } else {
                            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i], bundle.getString("format"));
                        }
                        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        if (msg_from.contains("PINSMS")) {
                            String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                            //String pinNo = msgBody.substring(msgBody.indexOf('"') + 1, msgBody.indexOf('"', msgBody.indexOf('"') + 2));
                            String pinNo = msgBody.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                            Log.d("SMS", "From -" + msg_from + " : Body- " + msgBody);
                            //CodeVerification.insertCode(pinNo);

                            // Broadcast to Auto read Code sms
                            final String DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION = context.getPackageName() + ".CodeSmsReceived";
                            Intent intentCodeSms = new Intent(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION);
                            intentCodeSms.putExtra("varificationCode", pinNo);
                            context.sendBroadcast(intentCodeSms);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Exception caught", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have registered this receiver in my class programmatic because i know OTP sms will come after my submit button click & i unregister it after OTP read as i dont want to trigger this receiver for every SMS by registering it in menifest.

```
SmsListener smsListener = new SmsListener();
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(smsListener);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    registerReceiver(smsListener, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
```

**EDIT**

Put below receiver in your activity to get OTP code

```
final String DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION = activity.getPackageName() + ".CodeSmsReceived";
        try {
            activity.unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        activity.registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
```

On receiving code below method will be called

```
 /**
     * Receiving Call Log Changed broadcast
     */
    private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra("varificationCode")) {
                String youtOTPcode = intent.getStringExtra("varificationCode"));
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: how can i call it in my activity?

Comment: @DivyangPanchal thank you , its working fine .  can you please Confirm once Should we mannually unregister the broadcast receiver ?

Answer (score 0):

For Marshmallow you have to ask users to give permissions. It's not given by default even if you declare it in `manifest`. **You need to add code to get runtime permission for marshmallow devices.**

For now just for checking you can go to `settings --> Apps --> go to your in the list --> click on permissions --> Enable SMS permission.` Then restart your app and check is it working.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Change MyOtpActivity to

```
public class MyOTP extends BaseActivity{

    EditText txtotp;
    Button btnSubmitOtp;
    private UpdateOTPReceiver mUpdateOtpReceiver;
    private SMSReceiver mSmsReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_otp);

        txtotp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtOtp);
        btnSubmitOtp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

        btnSubmitOtp.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mUpdateOtpReceiver = new UpdateOTPReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mUpdateOtpReceiver, new IntentFilter("UPDATE_OTP"));
        registerSMSReceiver();
    }

    private void registerSMSReceiver() {
        mSmsReceiver = new SMSReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mSmsReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
    }

    private class UpdateOTPReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent != null) {
                String msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
                Toast.makeText(MyOTP.this,"Message: "+msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

In SmsReceiver

```
Public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle data = intent.getExtras();

        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) data.get("pdus");

        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
            SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

            String sender = smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
            //ToDo check your sender 
            String messageBody = smsMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

            Intent updateTokenIntent = new Intent("UPDATE_OTP");
            updateTokenIntent.putExtra("msg", getVerificationCode(messageBody));
            context.sendBroadcast(updateTokenIntent);
        }

    }

    private String getVerificationCode(String message) {
        if (message == null) {
            return null;
        }

        int index = message.indexOf("is");
        int index_last_length = message.indexOf(".");
        if (index != -1) {
            int start = index + 3;
            return message.substring(start, index_last_length);
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Cannot Read a SMS having OTP word in it through broadcast receiver because of google policy.

Comment: Please refrain adding a comment as answer

Answer (score 0):

You Cannot Read a SMS having OTP word in it through broadcast receiver because of google policy is well said by Ridhika....
OTP messages can only be read by app that has its HashCode in the message body.

Comment: seems more like a comment

Comment: yeah i thought i do have have enough reputation to comment