# Sms service permission cannot work in lower version

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, one-time-password

In my application i am using SMSbroadcastreciever but when i am running app on lollipop or greater version it works but when i am running on lower version it sms cannot read automatically.
when i am going in permission of app in device the sms recieve not granted in kitkat even i have given runtime permission in app and also in manifest file

in other version code works fine:

Here is my code:

```
public class MySMSBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get Bundle object contained in the SMS intent passed in
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] smsm = null;
        String sms_str = "";

        if (bundle != null) {
            // Get the SMS message
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            smsm = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < smsm.length; i++) {
                smsm[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

                sms_str += "\r\nMessage: ";
                sms_str += smsm[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                sms_str += "\r\n";
                sms_str = sms_str.replaceAll("[^0-9?!\\.]", "");

                String Sender = smsm[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                //Check here sender is yours
                Intent smsIntent = new Intent("otp");
                smsIntent.putExtra("message", sms_str);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(smsIntent);

            }
        }
    }
}



    <receiver android:name=".Otpsms.MySMSBroadCastReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


 MySMSBroadCastReceiver receiver = new MySMSBroadCastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("otp")) {
                final String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                if (et_code_otp != null) {
                    et_code_otp.setText(message);
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SMS Broadcast Receiver not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019987/sms-broadcast-receiver-not-working)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot read OTP from message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42152924/cannot-read-otp-from-message)

Comment: i have added all permission and also runtime it cannot get permission to lowest version